# Как сделать так, чтобы питон вывел только один раз print()?

Tags: python, print

```
import random
import keyboard
game = True
kip = keyboard.is_pressed

while game:
        print("text(Нажмите N, если нет и Y, если да)")
        if kip("y"):
            print("yes")
            game = False
        elif kip("n"):
            print("no")
            game = False
```

В выводе мне даёт: text(Нажмите N, если нет и Y, если да) бесконечно, до того момента, пока я не нажму одну из клавиш. Мне нужно, чтобы из print() текст выводился только 1 раз, не завершая loop

Answer (score 2):

```py
print("text(Нажмите N, если нет и Y, если да)")
while game:
    if kip("y"):
        print("yes")
        game = False
    elif kip("n"):
        print("no")
        game = False
```

А вообще по хорошему есть метод `keyboard.read_key`, Который блокирует поток программы пока пользователь не нажмёт кнопочку, и не будет постоянно опрашивать буфер ввода.

```py
key = keyboard.read_key()
if key == 'y':
   print("yes")
elif key == 'n'
   print("no")
```

Comment: Спасибо, только сейчас заметил что sleep(1) там лишнее

Comment: Боже, спасибо тебе за то что ты есть, Eugen X!!!